# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setHours' of undefined

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, javascript, sharepoint-designer

I want to calculate the total days of leave that can be apply in weekday.

startDate & endDate value i take from their fields in format of (month/day/year)

I have found the uncaught type error in this line -> **startDate.setHours(0,0,0,1);**

What is this? Anyone can help?

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js','SP.ClientContext',workingDaysBetweenDates);

function workingDaysBetweenDates() {

var startDate = fd.field('StartDate').value();
var endDate = fd.field('_EndDate').value()

// Validate input
if (endDate < startDate)
    return 'Invalid !';

// Calculate days between dates
var millisecondsPerDay = 86400 * 1000; // Day in milliseconds
startDate.setHours(0,0,0,1);  // Start just after midnight
endDate.setHours(23,59,59,999);  // End just before midnight
var diff = endDate - startDate;  // Milliseconds between datetime objects    
var days = Math.ceil(diff / millisecondsPerDay);

// Subtract two weekend days for every week in between
var weeks = Math.floor(days / 7);
var days = days - (weeks * 2);

// Handle special cases
var startDay = startDate.getDay();
var endDay = endDate.getDay();

// Remove weekend not previously removed.   
if (startDay - endDay > 1)         
    days = days - 2;      

// Remove start day if span starts on Sunday but ends before Saturday
if (startDay == 0 && endDay != 6)
    days = days - 1  

// Remove end day if span ends on Saturday but starts after Sunday
if (endDay == 6 && startDay != 0)
    days = days - 1  

return days;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably this error occurs since [setHours()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setHours) is a function of [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object, but in your case `startDate` and `endDate` variables are of `String` type:

```
var startDate = fd.field('StartDate').value();
var endDate = fd.field('_EndDate').value()
```

**Solution**

Create a [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) objects:

```
var startDate = new Date(fd.field('StartDate').value());
var endDate = new Date(fd.field('_EndDate').value());
```

Answer (score 0):

This error is telling you that the `startDate` variable is undefined, i.e. it's empty, there's nothing in it.

You should check that your method of getting the start date from the form is working. I.e. check `fd.field('StartDate').value();`

Are you using the [SharePoint Forms Designer](http://spform.com/documentation/js/manager) tool? Have you included the Forms Designer script file?

If you've taken this code from elsewhere you will need to get the start and end date in a different way. jQuery is an option in this case.